# How to update a variable within a View.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Consider this simple user profile:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    onboarding_step = models.SmallIntegerField(default='1')
```

What is the simplest method it increment the `onboarding_step` within UserProfile each time a separate form from a different model is submitted? For example:

Here's the ModelForm (from a separate model, Site) I am submitting:

```
class OnBoardingProgressForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Site
            fields = ( 'abc', 'xyz', )
```

And here is the view.py for the form:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = OnBoardingProgressForm( request.POST )
        if form.is_valid():
            ....
            THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK BUT IS MY BEST GUESS:
            last = request.user.profile
            last.onboarding_step = 2
            ....
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = current_user
            obj.save()

            return render(request, "nextpage.html", {'form': form })
```

How can I increment the `user.onboarding_step` by `1`?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are having problems here. You know how to get the user from the request, and you know how to add a number, and you know how to save the object. What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I don't know the correct code syntax though (or where to begin!)

Comment: But I'm still having serious trouble understanding that. You *know* how to do all these things, you've shown that in your previous question and in this one. You have `current_user` already; you know how to go from the user to the userprofile model, and you know how to add a number to another number. So which bits don't you know how to do?

Comment: How do I get the variable to save in the  userprofile model, when I am submitting a form for the OnBoardingProgress model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = OnBoardingProgress( request.POST )
        if form.is_valid():
            ....
            // Can I increment the code here? //
            ....
            obj = form.save(commit=False)                
            obj.user = current_user
            obj.save()

            user_obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            user_obj.onboarding_step = user_obj.onboarding_step + 1
            user_obj.save()

            return render(request, "nextpage.html", {'form': form })
```

or you can make autoincrement field also.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work (no error message); possibly because you're relying on onboarding_step being in OnBoardingProgress, which it isnt?

Comment: what exactly do you want? my edited code will increment onboarding_step every time save forms. 
Do you want increment by 1 by userwise?

Comment: the model I am trying to update is different from the one with the form. the form has no fields relating to the model.

Comment: thanks, I am submitting a form for the model `site`, and I want to increment a field in a separate model, `userprofile`

Comment: amazing, thanks. for interest, why did it not work when i tried 'onboarding_step = request.user.profile.onboarding_step + 1'?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `UserProfile` object for the current user and then increment the value of the attribute of `onboarding_step`.

Try this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = OnBoardingProgress(request.POST)
    current_user = request.user
    if form.is_valid():  
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=current_user)[0] # get the user profile object for the current user
        user_profile.onboarding_step += 1 # increment the value  
        user_profile.save() # save the object                 
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = current_user
        obj.save()

        return render(request, "nextpage.html", {'form': form })
```